# Serving multiple pages from the same URL

Tags: nginx, web, web-applications, authentication

We want to implement something like facebook, where the login page and the web application are served at the same URL i.e., www.facebook.com

Currently in our app we have the login page being served at

```
www.ourapp.com
```

and the web application running at

```
www.ourapp.com\portal
```

We are using Nginx and it looks like Nginx does not allow 2 root/index directives to be served from the same location (example: www.ourapp.com), therefore we have to have to have 2 different customer facing URL's. Is it possible to conslidate the 2 URLs under www.ourapp.com?

Comment: Sure. You can proxy the request to your web app and then have your webapp perform authentication checks, instead of having nginx do it.

Comment: you wont be able to do this on client side easily due to security.. there are few workarounds though. Best is doing it through server..